# LVM stripes fewer than number of PVs

Tags: lvm

On CentOS 7, I created an 18TB LVM logical volume using option -i 8 (# of stripes = 8).  I should have used -i 18, to stripe across 18TB.  Update: 18 physical volumes; the VG has 24 1TB PV's, but that's not relevant to this question.

After creating the LV, I created a file system, which now shows 18TB free.

Current info:

```
# pvs
PV                      VG      Fmt  Attr PSize     PFree                        
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0 
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g        0
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
/dev/mapper/some-number volname lvm2 a--  <1024.00g  <767.99g
```

---

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               volname
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        24
  Metadata Sequence No  120
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                24
  Act PV                24
  VG Size               <24.00 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              6291432
  Alloc PE / Size       4718592 / 18.00 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       1572840 / <6.00 TiB
  VG UUID               Ib4B9R-dRK3-NjgQ-tPl4-Q68d-mcL4-TqvNJ2
```

---

```
# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/volname/data
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                volname
  LV UUID                tMnw3i-3QYR-EMst-uTFE-sxuT-kfgg-3trbP5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  . . .
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                18.00 TiB
  Current LE             4718592
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           253:37
```

So what does it mean to stripe across only 8 physical volumes, when the volume group has 18 physical volumes?  (Each PV is 1TB.)  What will happen when disk usage exceeds 8TB?

I could not find an answer for this.  So any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If the IO is distributed over fewer disks it will have a bit more random access time on the remaining disks as they are more busy. But if that matters depends on how fast the disks are and how much random/concurrent load you throw at it.

Comment: What command did you add `-i 8` to?

Comment: Here is the command:  lvcreate -n data -L 18T -i 8 --stripesize 128 volname

Comment: Let's say I write a 10MB file.  Because I have 8 stripes, then the first 128KB will go on PV#1, the next 128KB on PV#2, etc., up to PV#8.  Then where do the remaining bytes in the file go?

Comment: Also:  each of the PVs is a LUN in an EMC SAN.